# I could not understand what the mistake is?

Tags: html

using ID attribute in html code:

[image: using ID attribute in html code]

I have added the "id attribute" but the challenge is not accepting it. It is saying that you must use the id attribute.

I have already tried other examples instead of [<p] in id attribute but it is not accepting it. but as I have written the code, when I click on working of code (see below) jump to bottom, it take us to the bottom, as it function.

[image: working code]

I couldn't find the mistake plz help

Comment: Use instead of a picture the code feature here, that the community can reproduce it

Comment: @Alex now the problem is solved  but if i need help next  time i will use code feature  thanks for helping me knowing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and use this:

```
<footer id="footer"></footer>
```

It says footer tag should have an id named `footer`.
So, you should put an `id="footer"` at the footer tag, not the p tag or any other tag.

And you should edit your current footer tag, not make a new one

Comment: But after doing that it ...didn't work but another mistake appear saying that "there should be only one footer tag"....what do i do about it? There is no footer tag except the one you told and the one written after a href command #footer

Comment: @Jannat-ul-FatimaTareen but what?

Comment: @Jannat-ul-FatimaTareen and how it didn't work?

Comment: @Jannat-ul-FatimaTareen ah, no, don't add it, just put the id on the current footer tag. and see how does it work

Comment: @Jannat-ul-FatimaTareen and check the update too.

Comment: i was adding id attribute in the current footer tag

Comment: @Jannat-ul-FatimaTareen Oh, okay so it's fixed now?

Comment: but when i made another footer tag without removing the previous one it worked

Comment: @Jannat-ul-FatimaTareen glad it helped! is there a check mark beside the answer? if then, please click it. then, you'll accept this answer.

Comment: the tick one? i have done it..